# Group by first letter alphabetically and pass id

Tags: php, sql, foreach

In a relation to this solved post: [Group by first letter, alphabetically, best way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576075/group-by-first-letter-alphabetically-best-way)

how can i pass $id from the database into this foreach loop:

```
$res = array();

foreach($film as $f) {
    $currentletter = substr(html_entity_decode($f->title),0,1);
    $res[$currentletter][] = html_entity_decode($f->title);
}

foreach($res as $key=>$val){
   echo $key;
   foreach($val as $reqvals){
      echo $reqvals;
   }
}
```

Comment: What's `id`? Where's it being generated? Is it a fixed string? From a database? Part of `$res`? What do you want to do with it in the for loop?

Comment: Hey sorry, for id I mean the $id from a database.
As I pass $name, I need to extract the $id of every elements.

Comment: There's no need in that code to have two separate loops. You can move everything inside your `mysql_fetch_array()` - you can access all the database fields that way.

Comment: The two separate loops are, one for the alphabet letters and one for all the names. How can I extract $id if foreach are only for the names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly from the comments, you can merge the loops into one; you don't need two separate loops. I'm assuming that the fields in your database are 'name' and 'id'; it's assuming that you're sorting your database query, too.

```
$currentletter = '';

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $name = $r['name'];       // Read the variables from the row
    $id = $r['id'];

    $thisletter = substr($name,0,1);
    if ($currentletter != $thisletter) {  // only print out the letter if it's changed
        $currentletter = $thisletter;
        echo $currentletter;
    }

    echo $name;
    echo $id;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the $val in the foreach it means that your `$val` is an array. So the $key will be unique for your `$val` array. And you can pass the $key in the foreach by this way:

```
 $k = $key;
   foreach($val as $reqvals){
      echo "Supar Key: "$k." ".$reqvals;
      echo "<br>";
   }
```